# itunes connect 'test user' not working with in-app purchase

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I created an iTunes connect test user to test my in-app purchase. While testing on my device iTunes doesn't seem to recognize this test user connect even though I have verified it.

Am I missing some step ? I'd like to test my in app purchase.

Comment: You may also want to add more error logging. Can your app read the list of available in app purchases from the store? Or are you putting a static list of the in-app purchase identifiers in your app?

Comment: I'm able to retrieve the list from itunes connect. when it asks me to enter the credentials to purchase the app, and i use the test user account , it says invalid user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. It was solved by deleting the app on my iPad and then relaunching it from XCode.

Answer (score 0):

The in-app purchase process is very particular about your app settings. Be sure the app is signed with a provisioning profile/code signing identity that matches your app identifier com.yourcompany.yourapp and not built with your team profile.